# Modify local file with Airflow running on Windows (with Docker Compose)

Tags: windows, docker-compose, airflow

I have Airflow running on Windows using Docker Compose.
I created a DAG which appends data to a SQLite database.
Currently the DAG works with the database file being inside the Docker container but I'd like it to be on my local machine. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a volume in your docker-compose refering to the file you want to share between the container and your computer